# Division by Zero even after checking for zero in Pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have this line of code:

```
day['bar_polarity'] = np.where(day['bar_sum'] == 0.0, 0.0, day['bar_return']/day['bar_sum'])
```

And its throwing up

```
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

But how can that be when I am specifically checking for zero in the denominator? day['bar_sum'] is a float.

Comment: You check for zero **after** you already performed the division. You have many alternatives, for example `m = day['bar_sum'].eq(0) ; ay.loc[m, 'bar_polarity'] = day.loc[m, 'bar_return']/day.loc[m, 'bar_sum']`

Comment: you mean ne(0) for the statement above I presume! But I got the idea, create a mask using eq/ne. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I meant `ne`, sorry too late to fix it ;)